# Excel 2010 displaying blank screen while generating Excel with HTML

Tags: html, excel, coldfusion, excel-2010, ms-office

**Issue:** Excel display blank screen in Microsoft Excel 2010. Works fine if you have Version 2007

Code which generates Excel report -

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyReports.xls" />
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet> 
    <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 11"> 
    <style> <!--table @page{} --> </style> <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet> <x:Name></x:Name> <x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes> </x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions> </x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></ x:ExcelWorkbook> </xml> <![endif]-->
```

I checked Microsoft community site but don't find any solution so far.
If you guys faced similar Issue or you think above code needs to be modified, please help.

For Reference: HTML markup to Excel - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-dynamic-excel-using-html/

Comment: We faced a similar issue when excel 2007 came out.  Our solution was to stop using html for rendering data in excel and started using the POI.  That was before the spreadsheet tags came into ColdFusion.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: [Excel workbooks may not open after MS16-088 is installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507)

> The Microsoft Excel team has made a change in the behavior of certain
> file types to increase security. This change is included in the July
> 2016 security updates (MS16-088).
>
> Previously, when you tried to open an HTML or XLA file from an
> untrusted location, Excel opened the workbook without using Protected
> View security. After the security updates are installed, Excel no
> longer opens the workbook... There is no warning or other indication
> that the file was not opened.

Currently it has to be fixed on the client computer, but it looks like an upcoming update will fix it.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your input.

Answer (score 2):

MS did release patches for this behavior which they implemented on purpose.  Here's their blog about it: [Update 8/9/2016: Excel Workbooks may not open after installing MS16-088](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2016/07/22/excel-workbooks-may-not-open-after-installing-ms16-088/)

Here's a few workarounds we found for users:

- Open Excel
- Go to *File* --> *Options* --> *Trust Center* --> 
  *Trust Center Settings* --> *Protected View*
- Uncheck *"Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet"*

OR

- Open Windows Control Panel and open *Internet Options* --> *Security* tab
- Single click the *Trusted Sites* icon
- Click the *Sites* button and type in: *yoursite.com*
- Click the *Add* button --> *Close* --> *OK*

Another user-side workaround:

- Right click on the Excel file -> *Properties*
- Then unblock the file under *Security* -> Under *General* tab.
- Then Click *Apply* and *OK*.

Comment: Here's a few workarounds we found for users:  Open Excel. Go to File-->Options --> Trust Center --> Trust Center Settings --> Protected View --> Uncheck "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet" check box.
OR....Open your Windows Control Panel and open Internet Options-->Security tab-->Single click the Trusted Sites icon-->Sites button-->type: https://www.yoursite.com>Add button-->Close-->OK

Comment: Another user-side workaround: right click on excel file -> Properties -> and then need to unblock the file under Security - under tab - General. Then need to click Apply and Ok.

Comment: Thanks P Mascari for your input.